# Kendo-ui grid virtualization of remote data

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a web service that returns around 100,000 records of data. The returned data is an array of json objects which has the structure as follows:

```
[
{"name": "Aron", id: 1, type: "R"},
{"name": "Tina", id: 2, type: "R"},
{"name": "Phil", id: 3, type: "R"}
]
```

I want to use the `kendoGrid`, and I want to know if using the `scrollable: { virtual: true }` option is sufficient or should I have to reformat the data.

Answer (score 0):

You dont have to change your data, you just need to initiate an `kendoGrid()` and in you config put `scrollable: { virtual: true }` I did an  [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/m88d0zqv/)

Hope this help